# Where can I save the string in memory to avoid losing the content of DS?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have the following code:

```
[bits 16]
org  0x100

segment .text
    global start

start:
    lea si,[msg0]
    call print

    call gets

    lea si,[msg1]
    call print

    lea si,[ds:0]
    call print

    ; Termina el programa
    mov ah,00h
    int 21

gets:
    xor bx,bx
    mov ds,bx

gets_start:
    ; Leemos un caracter
    mov ah,00h
    int 16h

    ; Comprobamos si se presiono enter
    cmp ah,$1C
    je gets_end

    ; provocamos eco
    mov dl,al
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    ; Almacenamos el caracter
    mov [ds:bx],al
    inc bx
    jmp gets_start

gets_end:
    ; agregamos 0 al final de la cadena
    xor al,al
    inc bx
    mov [ds:bx],al

    ; Nueva linea
    mov dl,0xA
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    ret

print:
    ; Movemos el caracter a dl
    mov dl,[si]

    ; Comprobamos si el caracter es 0
    cmp dl,0
    je print_end

    ; Imprimimos el caracter
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    ; Avanzamos al siguiente caracter
    inc si
    jmp print

print_end:
    ; Termina de imprimir
    ret

segment .data
    msg0 db "Ingrese su nombre: ",0
    msg1 db "Hola ",0
```

But in `gets` I use the DS register to save an string and I lose the reference to the DS register (therefore I can't print the `msg1`). Where I can save the string?

I am new to assembler and I am learning about memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can save nearly any 16-bit register on the stack:

```
push ds
...
pop ds
ret
```

Note that the registers must be read in the reverse order they were stored. The following example would exchange the values of `ax` and `ds` because the old value of `ax` was stored last so it will be read first:

```
push ds
push ax
...
pop ds
pop ax
```

Note in this context that `ret` (at least when using near memory models) actually means `pop ip`. So you must have read all values stored to the stack 
back into registers before doing a `ret` instruction.

2) You are writing the string to address `DS:BX=0:0`.

In real mode this address contains the interrupt table. Writing data there is not a good idea: If the string is long enough the computer will definitely crash!

It would make more sense to do it like this:

```
    ...

gets:
    lea bx, [strgbuf]
gets_start:

    ...

segment .data
    msg0 db "Ingrese su nombre: ",0
    msg1 db "Hola ",0
    ; Space for the string
    strgbuf db "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: This looks fine but does dynamic memory exist like c?

Comment: @CristoferFuentes Depends on the operating system.

Comment: For dynamic memory you have three possibilities: 1) Use the stack. This however would mean that the memory is "freed" when returning from a function using "ret". 2) Use the operating system 3) Use a larger memory area and do the dynamic memory handling yourself.